# Как соединиться с БД в php и MySQL

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, база-данных, mysql

Всем привет. Использую код php.

```
 $username = "exxtazzy";
$password  = "m2uyYd5KYeiTdYeu3fYt024tup=PQI15nuIo8evh";
$hostname = "localhost";
$dbName = "exxtazzy";
/* создать соединение */
mysql_connect($dbName, $username, $password) or die  ("Не могу соедениться". mysql_error());;
$res =mysql_query("CREATE TABLE phone_list(
        id INT PRIMARY KEY,
        name varchar(15),
        Phone varchar(6)
        ",NULL ) or die  ("Ошибка соеденения". mysql_error());
echo $res;
mysql_close()or die  ("Не могу закрыться". mysql_error());;
?>
```

Пароль ввожу правильный и вводил его при переходе с хостинга на локальный сервер. Как так почему я не могу соединиться с бд? Как так почему я не могу соединится с бд? Пароль изменен так что не пытайтесь чего то сделать.

Comment: Сам mysql запущен?

Comment: пропингуйте хост exxtazzy, и проверте открыт ли на нем порт от mysql

Comment: die('Ошибка соединения: ' . mysql_error());
строку списал и теперь выскакивает 
 Ошибка соединения: 

А бд я импортировал с сайта, так что он должен быть запущен

Comment: Текущий код у меня 
$username = "exxtazzy3_nick";
$password = "m2uyYu5KYeiTdYeu3fYQ024~up=PQI1InuIo8evh";
$hostname = "localhost";
$dbName = "products";
/* создать соединение */
mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) OR DIE("Не могу создать соединение ");
  die('Ошибка соединения: ' . mysql_error());

 "CREATE TABLE 'phone_list'(
  'id' INT PRIMRY KEY
  'name' varchar(15)
  'Phone' varchar(6)
  );"
 ?>

Comment: что за mysql_query? Знаю что она посылает запрос активной базе данных сервера, на который ссылается переданный указатель, но мне это ничего не говорит

Comment: Не получится. Слишком много ошибок. (1) апострофы у имён полей и имени таблицы -- выкинуть или заменить на обратные. (2) поля в списке разделять запятыми. (3) вместо PRIMRY написать PRIMARY

Comment: $connect = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) OR DIE("Не могу создать соединение " . mysql_error());
 "CREATE TABLE phone_list(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY
  name varchar(15)
  Phone varchar(6)
  )";
Я вобще правильно поиск делаю. Там где ph ничего не выскакивает
http://imm.io/WVMc

Comment: Что касается текста из комментария -- там лажа. Если сразу за mysql_connect идёт текстовая константа "CREATE TABLE ...", то что Вы от неё хотите? Константа -- она константа и есть. Ошибок не создаст, но и делать ничего не сделает. Иное дело `$res = mysql_query("CREATE TABLE ... ");` ($res -- TRUE или FALSE, в зависимости от успеха операции).

Кстати, результат mysql_connect лучше бы сохранить, для закрытия в конце работы.

Comment: **НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЙТЕ РАСШИРЕНИЕ mysql** используйте mysqli или PDO

Comment: mysql - устарело и в будущем поддерживаться не будет, это не ответ на вопрос, а волонтерская программа.

Comment: @eicto На будущее -- да. Но сейчас ошибки лежат там, где они будут лежать и при использовании mysqli или PDO.

Comment: > localhost
> не пытайтесь чего то сделать

Так все и разбежались.

Answer (score 5):

Ну во-первых:

```
$username = "exxtazzy3_nick";
$password = "m2uyYu5KYeiTdYeu3fYQ024~up=PQI1InuIo8evh";
$hostname = "localhost"; $dbName = "products"; / создать соединение /
mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) OR DIE("Не могу создать соединение " . mysql_error());
```

А во-вторых: что же говорит mysql_error() ? Ничего? А то из Вашего комментария это не понятно.

В том, что Вы привели есть бяка. Независимо от результата соединения выполняется die() и выполнение скрипта прекращается. А что там за "CREATE TABLE..." ?

Comment: Скопировал ваш код отсюда и никакой ошибки не вылезает, но в базе я так и не нашел таблицы с именем phone_list

Comment: Так, значит mysql_connect никакой ошибки не обнаруживает. А phone_list в базе products есть? Если с консоли подключиться

     mysql products

(параметры --user=exxtazzy3_nick --password=m2uyYu5KYeiTdYeu3fYQ024~up=PQI1InuIo8evh) и сказать `show tables;` , то эта самая phone_list в списке будет?

Comment: Базы products нет, там другая база, я кстати изменил переменную $dbName на имя своей базы, таблицы так и нет.

Comment: Так если не ругается на mysql_connect, то может стоит посмотреть, есть ли там эта таблица? Например, выполнить запрос типа

      $result = mysql_query("show tables");

и вывести результаты этого запроса?

Comment: Что вы пытаетесь сделать после того как установили соединение с mysql? И как понимать строки "CREATE TABLE 'phone_list'(
        'id' INT PRIMRY KEY
        'name' varchar(15)
        'Phone' varchar(6)
        );"
в вашем вопросе?

Comment: Повторю вопрос @alexlz 
>А что там за "CREATE TABLE..." ?

сделайте mysql_query("CREATE TABLE 'phone_list'(
        'id' INT PRIMRY KEY
        'name' varchar(15)
        'Phone' varchar(6)
        );");

вдруг получиться;)

Comment: alexlz, скажите что за show tables? В справочнике я не нашел такой функции. Есть SHOW TABLE STATUS, но не show tables.

Comment: После соеденения с бд я хочу создать таблицу с именем phone_list.
строки CREATE TABLE 'phone_list'( 'id' INT PRIMRY KEY 'name' varchar(15) 'Phone' varchar(6) 
функция CREATE TABLE создает таблицу с именем phone_list
строка id - номер строки, name, phone - строки типа varchar содержит номер телефона и имя владельца

Comment: @exXtaZzy show tables: показывает не временные таблицы в данной базе http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html (где нибудь должно быть и на русском) Есть в mysql'евском хелпе.

Comment: @exXtazZy ну тогда эту строку надо передать параметром функции mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] ), где $query = "CREATE ...", второй параметр - это id соединения, который должна вернуть вам ф. mysql_connect(), в данном случае его можно опустить, поскольку соединение у вас единственное.

Comment: ребята, фигней занимаетесь...

Answer (score 3):

```
mysql_select_db($dbName);
```

Comment: (35 минут назад) alexlz, вывел echo, у меня ни false, ни true выскакивает. А при использовании mysql_query там не требуеся ввода пароля и логина. А как она соеденяется с бд?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php

link_identifier

    Соединение MySQL. Если идентификатор соединения не был указан, используется последнее соединение, открытое mysql_connect(). Если такое соединение не было найдено, функция попытается создать таковое, как если бы mysql_connect() была вызвана без параметров. Если соединение не было найдено и не смогло быть создано, генерируется ошибка уровня E_WARNING.

И, кстати, ошибки в запросе "CREATE TABLE ..." Вы исправили?

Comment: А как соеденение может быть активным если я только сейчас включил сервер. Что интересно, у меня не выскакивает ошибка уровня E_WARNING. У меня вобще ничего не выскакивает. Я исправил код который вы сказали.
$res =mysql_query("CREATE TABLE phone_list(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(15),
  Phone varchar(6)
  ",NULL ) or die  ("Ошибка соеденения". mysql_error());
echo $res

Comment: Что значит "только сейчас включил сервер"? Вообще не очень понятно, что у Вас происходит. И подредактируйте текст скрипта в вопросе, чтобы он отражал текущее состояние.

Comment: У меня сайт на локальном хостинге, так чтоб открыть и отладить сайт, нужно запустить сервер. у меня при запуске скрипта не выскакивает никакая ошибка и таблица не создается. Я вобще правильно выполняю поиск в http://imm.io/WVMc

Comment: Ну в этой картинке я ничего не понимаю. А вот если текст в вопросе подправлен, то уже интересней. Куда девался mysql_connect? Если его нет, то mysql_connect вызывается из mysql_query, но без параметров, т.е. все эти $username, $password, $hostname, $dbName никак не используются. Так что mysql_connect и mysql_close желательно бы вернуть. И, кстати, что выдаёт `echo $res;`?

Comment: Сделал и там такое выскачило. Короче в кодировке win-1251 выскакивает  РќРµ РјРѕРіСѓ СЃРѕРµРґРµРЅРёС‚СЊСЃСЏphp_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Этот хост неизвестен.
А в кодровке utf - 8 -  Не могу соеденитьсяphp_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: ���� ���� ����������. 
Ошибка выскакивает о коде mysql_connect($dbName, $username, $password) or die  ("Не могу соедениться". mysql_error()); Как будто неверные переменные. Сейчас заново скопирую пароль своей бд если таже ошибка, я уже не знаю что делать

Answer (score 3):

Если только начали юзать **php**, то уже сразу учите **PDO**. Ибо потом будет не привычно переходить.

Для начало нам нужен **php** от 5 версии.

А потом юзаем такой код:

`$db = new PDO('mysql:host=хост;dbname=база','пользователь','пароль');`

Ну и для примера, как потом выбирать записи с **MySQL**:

`$db->query("SELECT * FROM table");`

А вообще, прочитайте данные статейки:

1. [PDO - 1](http://habrahabr.ru/post/137664/)
2. [PDO - 2](http://vazelin.org.ua/archives/411/nachinaem-rabotu-s-pdo/)

Comment: PDO - это панацея от криворукости и неосиляторстве программистов. Человек успешно работающий с mysql_* успешно освоит и другие обёртки. Но человек начинающий с PDO, как правило, вообще не имеет представления о низкоуровневой работе с БД. Я бы не доверял свои проекты такому.

Comment: @istem вы сами то в  курсе низкоуровневой работы базы данных ? на какую глубину ? А-то может вы не стали бы доверять и тому кто 8" дискеты не видел или перфокартой не пользовался ?

Comment: Глупый спор.

Comment: это не спор, вы просто глупость сказали.